# How to load previous or next attachment with jquery ?

Tags: php, jquery, attachments, ajax

When i am on the single.php page, i show the first image attachment. 
then i would like to load the next (and previous) image attachments without reloading the page.

so in single.php i started with this to retrieve an array with the images html:

```
<?php $args = array('post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order'=> 'ASC', 'numberposts' => -1, 'post_status' => null, 'post_parent' => $post->ID ); 
      $attachments = get_posts($args);
  if ($attachments) {
            foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
                 $my_image = wp_get_attachment_image($attachment->ID, large) );
         $attachments_list[] = $my_image;
    }
  }
  reset($attachments_list);
  $first_image = current($attachments_list);
  echo $first_image; 
?>
```

and then in the script.js file i would like to get the value of my php array $attachments_list to do something like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var count = attachments_list.lenght();
    var init = 0;
    var current = init;

    if (count > 1) {
        $('#next-img').click(function() {
            if (current+1 < count) {
                current++
            } else if (current+1 === count) {
                current = init;
            }
            $('#image-container').html(attachments_list[current]);
        });
        $('#previous-img').click(function() {
            if (current > init) {
                current--
            } else if (current === init) {
                current = count-1;
            }
            $('#image-container').html(attachments_list[current]);
        });
    }
});
```

how can i retrieve the value of the php $attachments_list array to attachments_list inside the script.js file ? Json maybe ?

thanks for your attention

Comment: Just use a slider or Tabs for your gallery instead. This makes it look like a single view and you can switch through the images.

Comment: good idea, but the images are quite big and i don't want to load them all together. that's why i was looking for a more ajax-style solution.

Comment: try [this technique](http://www.ronakg.com/2011/05/passing-php-array-to-javascript-using-wp_localize_script/) for passing an array to a script via [`wp_localize_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script).

Answer (score 1):

@milo thanks ! i used [a technique](http://ottopress.com/2010/passing-parameters-from-php-to-javascripts-in-plugins/) found on the page you sent.

it's almost working.

I added this at the end of the previous single.php code :

```
array_unshift($attachments_list,"");
wp_enqueue_script('myscript');
wp_localize_script('myscript', 'attachments_list', $attachments_list);
```

To work, this code must be called before wp_head(). 
Then, for a mysterious reason, the first element (with the index 0) is printed after the JS array in the html head. That's why i had to unshift an empty string in the array before to send it with wp_localize_script.

Last thing:

```
var count = attachments_list.length;
```

is undefined. Everything is working fine when i replace count with a number, i can even access to the elements of the array with attachments_list[index], but the length of the array is undefined.

any idea about this ? 
thank you

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into your problem @rogaroga, and I believe resolved it in a less hackish manner.  I was attempting to attach an array of settings via `wp_localize_script`, where the array was constructed with repeated calls to `array_push( $array, $value )`, so the array was, if var_dump'd, like `{ [0] => { "stuff" }, [1] => { "etc" } }`, and then on a line all by his poor little lonesome after the var'd object of the settings in the little `<script>` tag printed by `wp_localize_script` was "stuff", breaking my script.  Same problem.  So, what I did was simply specify the indices of the array with the values of the array (definitely hackish), and `wp_localize_script` didn't append stuff after the var'd settings, which were happily now including that first setting, stuff.  So, the error-apparent is that `wp_localize_script` mishandles data passed to it whose index is 0; I haven't the foggiest why, but there's an empirically unfounded yet functional answer for you.

Comment: I edited your answer to remove your signature. This is expressly prohibited in [the wpse FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq).